# How to convert LaTeX code to SVG code or SVG file with python without requiring an internet connection?

Tags: python, svg, latex

I want to be able to take a line of LaTeX code and turn it into SVG code, or (even better) an actual SVG file. However, the kicker here is that I don't want to require that I have an internet connection-- I am willing to have to download a LaTeX distribution (like MiKTeX). I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/007gzs/latex2svg) (which is a wrapper around `dvisvgm`)

Comment: So what do I have to install?

Comment: Because I already have MiKTeX installed, but when I tried to get it to work, I got this error message: "Warning: libgs not found"

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. You need `dvisvgm` installed. Look at https://dvisvgm.de/Downloads/

Comment: I just downloaded it, still gave me the same error.

Comment: which OS are you on?

Comment: Should have mentioned that in the question: Windows.